# Not able to fetch Unicode data in Hindi language from PHP and MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, fetch, hindi

I have a database (utf8_unicode_ci), tables (utf8_unicode_ci), and a mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8").

I have one more problem today. I have one table and in that there are 10,000 records which is stored in unicode format in the Hindi language. I am using Xampp 1.6.2 Version. When I fetch data on the local machine, it's showing properly; say for example "select * from unicode_table order by id".

But if i upload it on my live server, it's not displaying any record. I tried to figure it out and I found that if I write:

```
select * from unicode_table order by id limit 0, 40
```

A query with `limit 0, 40` shows data,  and if I give `limit 0, 50` then it displays junk. So there is a problem in recordset/mysql query connection. Can any one help me out with this?

My live server is the latest update with PHP and MySQL and the server is maintained by one of the good hosting companies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you fetch the first 50 records via the mysql command line interface?

Comment: yes i can fetch all records from command line there is not problem in command line i had try fetching more then 200 record from command line too

Comment: Try to identify the row where the problem occurs. Copy the first 100 rows to another table and see if the problem persists. If you can define a small test data sample which shows the error, post it here or set up a sample at sqlfiddle.com

Comment: i had try that thing also but its give randomly well i will post some sample at sqlfiddle.com till night thanks alex

Answer (score 0):

Things to watchout for :
1. make sure with your html or php file that would render the content, has either : 
   i) `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>`
   OR
   ii).

```
<?php $page_html = "<html>";

    $page_html .= "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"content-type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">";

    $page_html .= "<body>";

    $page_html .= " process and display your content from the database here ";

$page_html .= "</body></html>";

    echo $page_html;
```

2. Make sure you have the right collation as stated below. ( :) all the best )

So in my case, I had tried changing the collation from `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for mysql and had to change it to `uft8_general_ci`.

Then pasted :

```
mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');
```

right before I did the SELECT command.

This is my code for reading from db :

```
/*

$DB_SERVER="db_server_name";
$DB_USER_READER="root";
$DB_PASS_READER="passw*rd";
$DB_NAME="db_name";
$DB_PORT="port number";

$SELECT_WHAT="`name_of_column_as_in_your_table`";
$WHICH_TBL="`table_name`";
$ON_WHAT_CONDITION="`id`='7'";

*/


$con = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER_READER, $DB_PASS_READER, $DB_NAME, $DB_PORT);//this is the unique connection for the selection

    mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');


        $slct_stmnt = "SELECT ".$SELECT_WHAT." FROM ".$WHICH_TBL." WHERE ".$ON_WHAT_CONDITION;

    $slct_query = mysqli_query($con, $slct_stmnt);

        if ($slct_query==true) {
//Do your stuff here . . . 
}
```

And it worked like a charm. All the best. The above code can work with reading chineese, russian or arabic or any international language from the database's table column holding such data.