# Retrieving Unicode text from MySQL causing ???? in output

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I am storing Unicode text `لاہور` in MySQL, I have set tables and columns to utf8_general_ci. The text `لاہور` is displaying correctly in MySQL. However if I echo that with PHP it shows `??????` on the browser window.

One thing to mention here: I have the whole document in Unicode and all words are displaying correctly, but they are written directly i.e. not coming from MySQL.

Even if I try

```
$p="لاہور";
echo $p;
```

It displays `لاہور` in the browser. Things go wrong only when retrieving from MySQL.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Please check this : may be helpful like a charm : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581474/not-able-to-fetch-unicode-data-in-hindi-language-from-php-and-mysql/36117532#36117532](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581474/not-able-to-fetch-unicode-data-in-hindi-language-from-php-and-mysql/36117532#36117532)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common cause for this is that your PHP script is being saved with another format (for example ASCII), you must be sure that your PHP script is also saved as UTF-8 or whatever codification you use in your database.

Another possible cause is that MySQL is not returning proper Unicode characters to your script, you may use `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")` or whatever encoding you want to use, before processing your queries, a good way to troubleshot this problem could be converting the string to their respective unicode codes and comparing them to see if they're the same.

Comment: The PHP script file (*.php), has an encoding (let's say ASCII), so you must be sure that both the enconding of the database and the enconding of the script file are the same (both UTF-8, for example) a good tool to change the encodign of the file is Notepad++.

Comment: I am uing notepad++ and I told you all before that I have whole file in .php format with UNICODE text, it is working fine except the database part

Comment: @Programer that is not recommended, you should use `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` instead. See the [note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php): *This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysql_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended. See the MySQL character set concepts section for more information.* `mysql_query` [does not affect mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for instance

Answer (score 1):

It may not always be sufficient to set the content type  using meta tags, I usually set it via the header directive as well as below.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your MySQL *connection* (as opposed to storage) has not been set to UTF-8, causing the UTF-8 data retrieved from MySQL to be converted to Latin1 (or similar), which cannot represent those characters and they are replaced with a `?`.

If you are using `mysql_`:

```
mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );
```

If you are using `mysqli_`:

```
$mysqli->set_charset( 'utf8' );
```

**before** you make any queries

If you are using `PDO`, add `charset=utf8` to the connection string.